# React-js undefined props dynamic page when accessing URL directly

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, webshop

I'm trying to create a webshop with React as front-end framework and have gotten stuck on the routing of the products. I currently have all the products in a json table and import these into my webshop which works fine when the product page is accessed through the link but whenever I go to the product page directly I get an error stating that my props are undefined. I have

```
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/products/:productId" component={Product} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
```

as my router to the product page and link to the page using:

```
<Link to ={{pathname:`/products/` + product.url, ProductdetailProps:{title: product.title, description: product.text, image: product.image}}}>
```

The Product page looks like this:

```
export const Product = ({location}) => {
        return (
        <div>
            <img src={location.state.image} alt={backupImage}/>
            <p>{location.state.title}</p>
            <p>{location.state.description}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Should I keep on "creating" the product pages this way and if so can someone help me with this or should make each product page seperately and link those?

Comment: Right, if you access the URL directly and ***not*** from *that* link then the extra data isn't sent with the route push. What routing/navigation library are you using? If the target page can be accessed directly then you should guard against potentially undefined data/props/etc. Can you include your `Product` component code?

Comment: I'm using the react-router-dom library

Comment: Shouldn't `ProductdetailProps` go in route `state` then? What version of react-router-dom?

Comment: What do you mean? I just started using react and have never really touched front-end development before so I'm still busy learning everything

Comment: I mean, it *should* be `to={{ pathname: "...", state: { ...whatever the route state should be ... }}}`. [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) This is why I asked version in case the component API is/was different.

Comment: Ah okay, I use react-router-dom v5.2.0 and react v17.0.1. I've also updated the comment with the product component if that helps

Comment: Provided the extra data in the `Link` works, my original comment still stands; *that* data is transient and only exists for the duration of the route transition to the next page. Direct navigation won't have it. I think you'll just need to check that `location.state` exists on that page and handle it accordingly, for example redirecting back to a main page in your app to get the data that page needs.

Comment: So it isn't possible to get the data when accessing the page directly? In that case might it be better to create the page in a different way so people can access the products directly?

Comment: No, sorry, this is how route state works. Your product page appears to use an `id`, so if you have your products stored in a global app state (state in common ancestor, React Context, redux, etc...) you could load the data from there, by id, and not have to rely on sending the correct data via a route push. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I think so, if I understand it correctly you would suggest having an id on each product which the Link references and uses to guide to the correct page and have the Product page also use that ID to create the website. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Close. The Product page would check the `productId` from `match.params` to lookup in "state" what product to load on the page.

Comment: But wouldn't that also give the same problem when users access the product page directly since the productId was not added in the route transition?

Comment: The `productId` is part of the URL, `path="/products/:productId"`. The URL itself defines the product to load on the page.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! Thanks for helping me out:) I'll try to work it out.